# Result not showing if large result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is giving me a headache. Its been 4 hours and I've just circling around it :(. My problem is when I am fetching large result from mysql to php it doesn't display anything. The total result are about 20000+ data. So what I did was limit the result to 1000 and it did display the result as expected.

Is there some configuration that I need to set or change?

My sample query below

doesn't work (when the result is more that 10000)

```
select * from `tbl_item` where `pricelist_id` = 1 and `published` = 'unpublished' and `type` = 'item' and `parent_id` = 0 and `tbl_item`.`status` <> 'inactive' order by `order` asc limit 10000
```

Work (Just limit the result to 1000)

```
select * from `tbl_item` where `pricelist_id` = 1 and `published` = 'unpublished' and `type` = 'item' and `parent_id` = 0 and `tbl_item`.`status` <> 'inactive' order by `order` asc limit 1000
```

Weird. Help anyone.

Regards,

Comment: Try `ini_set('memory_limit', '254M'); //your memory limit as string 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`

Comment: 20000 is very small amount of data for MySql to process, There must be something wrong with PHP config or your code. Show us your PHP code please and what is `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` has been set?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? You've tagged this question with PHP and Laravel, but haven't added any information about that. When you run the same query using MySQL shell, phpMyAdmin, Laravel, do you receive it faster? Have you checked for database indices?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the resultset takes too much memory. This would cause a fatal error, did you activate error_reporting?

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

You can set a higher memory limit by adding this to your script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M'); // would be really high, but good enough to investigate on the problem
```

You can then use `memory_get_peak_usage()` to display... well, the peak of memory consumption

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the below values in php.ini

1. max_execution_time
2. memory_limit

For e.g. :

```
 in php.ini
 max_execution_time = 3000 // seconds
 memory_limit = 512M
```

You can change this value at the run time using ini_set() function as per below.

```
 ini_set("max_execution_time", "3000"); // seconds
 ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
```

You can change the seconds as per your requirements.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this using mssql. My resultset was limited to 64512. 
Try to set MSSQL.TEXTSIZE or TEXTLIMIT.

If php is still ignoring it, you can also try to configure FREETDS (/etc/freetds/freetds.conf @ubuntu)

Comment: This does not look connected to this question after all - the OP asked about help for MySQL on a resultset of ~20k elements